Is there a method for disabling focus on SearchBar when closing default SearchView on mobile?
I'm implementing a basic SearchBar widget in my first mobile Flutter app, based on the code sample provided in the Flutter Docs for SearchBar.
The issue I'm facing is that the SearchBar remains focused when the leading "back-arrow" icon button is pressed when trying to exit the (default) search view, which contains suggestions. Due to this, the keyboard remains open on mobile devices.
Moreover, when the search view is open, pressing the device's back button first closes the keyboard, then pressing back again closes the search view and puts focus back on the SearchBar, which opens the keyboard again. This is terrible UX and coupled with the fact that I'm new to Flutter, I am sure that I am doing something incorrectly.
I've tried different approaches:

setting autoFocus on SearchBar to false
providing a _focusNode to SearchBar
using viewLeading to redefine the "back-arrow" icon button and have a custom onPressed. Then trying to unfocus using the _focusNode. Doesn't unfocus, but I was able to replicate the functionality of closing the search view with SearchController.close(null).

Here's my code (without the _focusNode part added in):
class _AddressSearchBarState extends State<AddressSearchBar> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SearchController? searchController;

    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: SearchAnchor(
        isFullScreen: false,
        viewLeading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            if (searchController != null) {
              searchController?.closeView(null);
            }
          },
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        builder: (BuildContext context, SearchController controller) {
          searchController = controller;

          return SearchBar(
            autoFocus: false,
            hintText: "Looking for an Address?",
            padding: const MaterialStatePropertyAll<EdgeInsets>(
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0)
            ),
            onTap: () {
              controller.openView(); // cannot use searchController due to null possibility
            },
            onChanged: (_) {
              controller.openView();
            },
            leading: const Icon(Icons.search),
          );
      },
        suggestionsBuilder: (context, controller) => {}, // TODO: populate with Google Maps suggestions
      ),
    );
  }
}


This worked for me:
     viewLeading: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () {
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
          });
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),


This is the route I've gone as well, but it is essentially a large button that opens the searchview instead of a searchbar opening a searchview.

Happy to learn of the existence of FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(). This is indeed a fine way to dismiss a keyboard in Flutter.
